# How do I pass a hidden input to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am very new to rails and javascript.  I have a table as shown below, I am trying to pass the item id and the selected category to an ajax call which  updates the item.id's category.

What is going wrong is I don't seem to be able to pass the correct it.id to the ajax call.  It passes the first it.id rather than tho one on the row I have selected. I have had this working but I did a lot of clean up of other code and it no longer works.  I guess I just did something lucky the first time around without really knowing how to do it.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
<% @itemised.each do |it| %>
<tr>
<td><%= it.date %> </td>
    <td><%= it.item  %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(it.value, :unit => "$") %></td>
<td><form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Submit"   onClick="singleItem(this.form)" >
<select name="list">
  <% @array_of_live_categories.each do |cats|  %>
     <option> <%= cats %> </option>
         <% end %>
      ## <option> <%= it.id %> </option>
</select>
<input type= "hidden" id="id" name="id" value= "<%= it.id %>">

</form>
</td>
```

I am using the following javascript to test.

```
function singleItem (form) {
Cat_index = form.list.selectedIndex;
Cat = form.list.options[Cat_index].text;
Item_id = document.getElementById('id').value;
 console.log(Item_id) ;
 console.log(Cat) ;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: '/items/single_categorise',
data: { id: Item_id, newcat: Cat},
});
}
```

I just included the ##  <%= it.id %>  as a way to prove that item.id does exist.

Below is a section of the source code, there is a lot more to it but from this I can see that the value being passed back looks correct.  However, when singleItem function is run it passes a different value (the value associated with the first item on the table).

```
</tr>
</tbody>
<tr>
<td>15/01/2015 </td>
<td>J P &amp; Y P Mahaffy</td>
<td>$1,500.00</td>


<td><form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value= "J P &amp; Y P Mahaffy">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Submit" onClick="singleItem(this.form)" >
<select name="list">
<option> bank fees </option>
<option> cash out </option>
<option> vehicle expenses </option>
<option> health </option>
<option> office expenses </option>
<option> income </option>
<option> entertainment </option>
<option> transfer </option>
<option> ird payment </option>
<option> unsorted </option>
<option> regular payment </option>
<option> interest </option>
<option> user a </option>
## <option> J P &amp; Y P Mahaffy </option>
</select>

</form>
</td>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Harleigh

Comment: It sounds like you might have duplicate ids on your page.  Have you double-checked for this?  Can you post a copy of the rendered markup?

Comment: Do you mean duplicate item.id's? yes i'm sure i don't have have these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't seem to be able to pass the correct `it.id`

That's because your `select` has no values:

```
<option>bank fees</option>
#-> should be -> <option value="...">bank fees</option>
```

Further, there are a number of issues to resolve:

> 1. You should *always* use Rails helpers for HTML elements (such as [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) etc)
> 2. You should keep your JS [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)
> 3. You need to make sure you're structuring your forms correctly

--

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <% @itemised.each do |it| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= it.date %> </td>
        <td><%= it.item  %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(it.value, :unit => "$") %></td>
        <%= content_tag :td do %>
          <%= form_tag "#", id: "category_form", data: { it-id: it.id } do %>
            <%= collection_select :list, :category_id, @array_of_live_categories, :first, :first, {}, id: "category_select" %>
            <%= submit_tag %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

The above will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "form#category_form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $id  = $(this).data("it-id");
  $cat = $(this).find("select#category_select").text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/items/single_categorise',
    data: { id: $id, newcat: $cat},
  });
}
```

---

Off topic, but a MUCH simpler version of what you're doing would be to use the `data-remote` option for `select` boxes:

```
<%= collection_select :category, :id, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, {data: { remote: true, url: url_for(controller: :items, action: :single_categorise)}} %>
```

This will just show a single select box, from which the `id` of the `category` you wish to send will be sent to the controller as `params[:category][:id]`. Unfortunately, it will not send the `it.id`

Comment: thanks for that.  I am getting a syntax error on this line.   <%= form_tag "#", id: "category_form", data: { it-id: it.id } do %>

Comment: ok think that just needed to be changed to "it-id" => it.id. Id is now being passed fine.

Comment: I am getting some strange params from this code. The id is correct but the :newcat is a mixture of all the options {"id"=>"Bnz  Z3594 Zskyway", "newcat"=>"b\nc\nv\nh\no\ni\ne\nt\ni\nu\nr\ni\nu", "controller"=>"items", "action"=>"single_categorise"}.  It seems to be the first letter of each category option preceded by a 'n'. Also why did you include :first :first in the code?

Comment: got a result - changed JS to $cat = $(this).find(":selected").text(); thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use Rails hidden tag

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'itemId', it.id %>
```

In you javascript

```
Item_id = document.getElementById('itemId').value;
```

Hope this will help you.